# Is there a limit in the number of simultaneous users in R shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, limit

I am preparing a survey of some 1,000 participants (net sample) in R shiny. It may well be that 100 users or so will participate simultaneously once the survey is launched. My problem is that I cannot simulate this situation beforehand but have to trust that it works, otherwise I will be in deep trouble. So my question is, if there is any limit in the number of parallel users (aside from the computational burden, which is a different issue).

I thought that there is no limit but then I realized that I can only open up to 5 shiny tabs in my browser (but another 5 in another browser and so on). Furthermore, I realized that Shiny Server Pro comes with a limit of 20 concurrent users, which makes no sense given that it should be more advanced than the free version. These things make me a bit uneasy if there are further limits, which I am not aware of.

Thank you for your help, Reinhard

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Shiny server is single threaded, there is not limit in the number of users but your app could be slower with multiple users at the same time. [Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217801418-Can-more-than-one-user-interact-with-a-Shiny-Server-application-concurrently-) are more details about it.

The Pro version is multi threaded and the limit of concurrent users is defined by the license that you buy (and the hardware resources).

If your app is just a survey without any strong computation, it should be able to handle many users at the same time with a minimal delay.